# check if coordinates are overlapping using numpy, matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, shapely

I need to check whether a square is overlapping with a defined polygon

Yes, it can be easily done using shapely as below

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import box
minx,miny,maxx,maxy=0,0,1,1
b = box(minx,miny,maxx,maxy)
polygon = Polygon([(230,478),(500,478),(432,154),(308,154)])
print(polygon.contains(b))
```

**Any alternate ways to achieve the same results using NumPy,matplotlib?**
(*fyi:shapely is not approved to use*)

Comment: Check if it helps: https://github.com/qwertyquerty/collision

Comment: @HetalThaker, Thank you so much.really interesting repo. but unfortunately, I couldn't use it just because it's not approved by our Organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (almost) do that with a few more steps. This runnable code shows all the steps with resulting plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

vts = np.array([(230,478),(500,478),(432,154),(308,154)])
pgon = patches.Polygon(vts, color="blue", alpha=0.5)

# 2 points defining a box
point1 = (300,357)  # upper-right point: (xmax,ymax)
point2 = (250,250)  # lower-left point:  (xmin,ymin)

# plot the polygon patch
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(pgon)

# check if the 2 points are inside the polygon patch?
pts_inside = pgon.contains_points(ax.transData.transform([point1, point2]))

print(pts_inside) # get [ True False] output

# plot points
ax.scatter(point1[0],point1[1], color="red", zorder=6)   # point1 inside
ax.scatter(point2[0],point2[1], color="green", zorder=6) # point2 outside

plt.show()
```

[image: pointsinpgon]

From the above code, you get

```
pts_inside
```

which contains vaues: [ True, False]. That means only point 1 is inside the polygon. If you get [True, True], both points are inside the polygon, but the rectangle box defined by the points may not.

Comment: even a single point inside the defined region means that some part of the rectangle is inside the polygon area. (i,e there is an overlap) so basically it helps me. Thank you so much